# Set default rake task outside of Rakefile

Tags: ruby, rake

Is it possible to set the default rake task from outside of the Rakefile. The standard behaviour is to have the following inside your Rakefile:

```
task :default => :my_awesome_task
```

This fails when I move it to a different file and then require the file in the Rakefile, because it cannot evaluate what `task` is...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

**Rakefile**

```
require 'rake_tasks'
```

**rake_tasks.rb**

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => :spec

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |task|
  task.exclude_pattern = 'spec/integration/**/*_spec.rb'
end
```

Comment: We need a very minimal example of your two files to understand what you mean.

Comment: @theTinMan Added an example.